# Why is response code always 0 when I can actually enter the http that provides the JSON?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, http

I'm trying to connect my Android Studio app to a website to pull and read a JSON but i always get response code 0. I tried using subscribe as desperate measure because just using GET or POST didnt even give me response codes, any ideas? I know the url is up because I can access it on any browser but the program does not want to interact with it, I would appreciate any help

```
            HttpServiceClass httpServiceClass = new HttpServiceClass(HttpURL);
            httpServiceClass.ExecutePostRequest()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                        }
                        public void onNext(String response) {
                            if (httpServiceClass.getResponseCode() == 0) {
                                Log.i("Error", "No tienes Conexion a Internet");
                                Error = "S";
                            } else if (httpServiceClass.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                                FinalJSonResult = httpServiceClass.getResponse();
```

Comment: Do you have intenret permission?  What URL are you going for-  is it http or https (if http, do you have cleartext enabled in your manifest)?

Comment: yes, i can't really share the url but it's not internal or LAN based. It does use https but worst case scenario it doesnt even go to the "if" statement and the process stops there, best case scenario it gets response code 0

Comment: I don't know this `HttpServiceClass`, but are you sure you should read the response code from the `httpServiceClass` and not from the `response`? This doesn't seem right.

Comment: Ahh, actually `response` is just a string.

Comment: What happens when you make this request in the browser or using a tool like Proxyman?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone that answered, turns out I just needed to skip the SSL certificate on the url so I added a TrustManager and that fixed it.